# Flutter - Text forms not moving above the keyboard upon opening

Tags: flutter, dart

I am fairly new to flutter and dart as a whole and i have been creating an application that interacts with firebase, this is the code for my registration screen. When clicking on a text input field the keyboard ends up blocking the forms and you cannot see what you are entering... I have tried many things such as singlechildscroll view and resizeToAvoidBottomInset and nothing seems to be affecting it. Anyone have any idea?

Register page:

```
class RegistrationPage extends StatefulWidget{
  const RegistrationPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
_RegistrationPageState createState() => _RegistrationPageState();
}

class _RegistrationPageState extends State<RegistrationPage> {

  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  //our form key
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  //editing controllers
  final firstNameEditingController = new TextEditingController();
  final lastNameEditingController = new TextEditingController();
  final emailEditingController = new TextEditingController();
  final passwordEditingController = new TextEditingController();
  final confirmPasswordEditingController = new TextEditingController();
  final cityEditingController = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //firstname Field
    final firstNameField = TextFormField(
        autofocus: false,
        controller: firstNameEditingController,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
        validator: (value)
        {
          RegExp regEx = new RegExp(r'^.{2,}$');
          if(value!.isEmpty)
          {
            return("First Name cannot be empty");
          }
          if(!regEx.hasMatch(value))
          {
            return("Enter valid name(min 2 characters)");
          }
          return null;

        },
        onSaved: (value) {
          firstNameEditingController.text = value!;
        },
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.face),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
            hintText: "First name",
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            )
        ));

    //Last name Field
    final lastNameField = TextFormField(
        autofocus: false,
        controller: lastNameEditingController,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
        validator: (value)
        {
          RegExp regEx = new RegExp(r'^.{2,}$');
          if(value!.isEmpty)
          {
            return("Last Name cannot be empty");
          }
          return null;
        },
        onSaved: (value) {
          lastNameEditingController.text = value!;
        },
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.face),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
            hintText: "Last name",
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            )
        ));

    //email Field
    final emailField = TextFormField(
        autofocus: false,
        controller: emailEditingController,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
        validator: (value)
        {
          if(value!.isEmpty)
          {
            return("Please enter your email");
          }
          //email validation
          if(!RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-z]").hasMatch(value))
          {
            return("Please enter a valid email");
          }

        },
        onSaved: (value) {
          emailEditingController.text = value!;
        },
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
            hintText: "Email address",
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            )
        ));
    //City
    final cityField = TextFormField(
        autofocus: false,
        controller: cityEditingController,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
        validator: (value)
        {
          RegExp regEx = new RegExp(r'^.{2,}$');
          if(value!.isEmpty)
          {
            return("City cannot be empty");
          }
          return null;
        },
        onSaved: (value) {
          cityEditingController.text = value!;
        },
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
            hintText: "City",
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            )
        ));

    //password Field
    final passwordField = TextFormField(
        autofocus: false,
        controller: passwordEditingController,
        obscureText: true,
        validator: (value)
        {
          RegExp regEx = new RegExp(r'^.{6,}$');
          if(value!.isEmpty)
          {
            return("Password is required!");
          }
          if(!regEx.hasMatch(value))
          {
            return("Enter valid password(Min. 6 characters)");
          }

        },
        onSaved: (value) {
          passwordEditingController.text = value!;
        },
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
            hintText: "Password",
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            )
        )
    );

    //Confirm password Field
    final confirmPasswordField = TextFormField(
        autofocus: false,
        controller: confirmPasswordEditingController,
        obscureText: true,
        validator: (value)
        {
          if (confirmPasswordEditingController.text  != passwordEditingController.text){
            return "Passwords do not match";
          }
          return null;
        },
        onSaved: (value) {
          confirmPasswordEditingController.text = value!;
        },
        textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
            hintText: "Confirm Password",
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            )
        )
    );
    final registerButton = Material(
        elevation: 5,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
        color: Colors.pink,
        child: MaterialButton(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
          minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          onPressed: () {
            signUp(emailEditingController.text, passwordEditingController.text);
          },
          child: Text("Register", textAlign:TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        )
    );
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(

          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.pink),
            onPressed:(){
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          )
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: new SingleChildScrollView(
              reverse: true,
                child: Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: Padding(

                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(36.0),
                      child: Form(
                        key: _formKey,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[

                            SizedBox(
                                height: 180,
                                child: Image.asset(
                                  "assets/logo.png",
                                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                                )),
                            SizedBox(height: 30),
                            firstNameField,

                            SizedBox(height: 10),
                            lastNameField,

                            SizedBox(height: 10),
                            emailField,

                            SizedBox(height:10),
                            cityField,

                            SizedBox(height: 10),
                            passwordField,

                            SizedBox(height: 10),
                            confirmPasswordField,

                            SizedBox(height: 10),
                            registerButton,

                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

Main.dart

```
Future<void> main() async { //asynchronous programming, waits for events to happen before producing a result
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); //in this case initializes the Firebase waits for a callback
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget { //Used to build application
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key); //Anything in here runs when the app starts
  ThemeData _appTheme() { //The login screen is first to load but this is not in place of main as it is bad practise
    final ThemeData base = ThemeData.light(); //Will be used for implementation of light and dark theme
    return base.copyWith(
      colorScheme: base.colorScheme.copyWith(
        primary: travelBlue,
        onPrimary: Colors.white,
        secondary: travelBlue,
        error: travelErrorRed,
      ),
    );
  }
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp( //Runs when main.dart is executed
      title: 'Login',
      theme: _appTheme(),
      home: LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try wrapping your column with padding

```
Padding(
  padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
        // your entire form widgets here
    ]
  )
)
```

Comment: Apologies, what you said worked on an emulator device but not a physical device so it is a local issue rather than an issue with your reply. Either way thank you!